# Entity Framework Error Updating Master Details Items

Tags: entity-framework

Hi everybody im trying to add new items to master detail records and i get the error:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "invOrden_InvOrdenDet_FK1". The conflict occurred in database "InventarioSIAIplus", table "dbo.InvOrden", column 'IDorden'.
The statement has been terminated.

This error Happens when i add a new item to the detail.

Thanks for any help.
CODE I'M USING FOR ADDING AND UPDATING THE THE DATA:
   InventarioSIAIplusEntities SIAplusContext = (InventarioSIAIplusEntities)(Session["context"]);
            InvOrden orden;

```
        if (txtIDorden.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
             orden = new InvOrden();
             orden.IDcentro = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCentros.SelectedValue);
             orden.estado = ddlEstadoOrden.SelectedValue;
             orden.fecha = DateTime.Now;
             orden.comentario = txtComentarioOrden.Text;
             orden.usuarioCrea = "Jeanc";                
             SIAplusContext.AttachTo("InvOrden",orden);              
        }
        else
        {
             int idorden = Convert.ToInt32(txtIDorden.Text.Trim());
             orden = SIAplusContext.InvOrdenes.Where(c => c.IDorden == idorden).First();
                //orden.lo.getOrden());                
             orden.estado = ddlEstadoOrden.SelectedValue;
             orden.fecha = DateTime.Now;
             orden.comentario = txtComentarioOrden.Text;
             orden.usuarioCrea = "Jeanc";

        }

        foreach (var item in DetalleMedicamentosOrden)
        {
            if (item.InvOrdenReference.Value == null)
            {
                item.InvOrden = orden;

            }
        }

        SIAplusContext.SaveChanges();
```

CODE FOR ADDING ITEMS TEMPORARY TO THE DETAIL

InventarioSIAIplusEntities SIAplusContext = (InventarioSIAIplusEntities)(Session["context"]);
            List meds = DetalleMedicamentosOrden;

```
         //Datos Detalle
        InvOrdenDet ordenDetalle = new InvOrdenDet();            
        ordenDetalle.cantidadSol = uscAgregarMedicamentos1.Cantidad;
        ordenDetalle.cantidadApr = uscAgregarMedicamentos1.CantidadAprobada;

        ordenDetalle.comentario=uscAgregarMedicamentos1.Comentario;
        ordenDetalle.comentario = uscAgregarMedicamentos1.Comentario;
        ordenDetalle.IDmedicamento=uscAgregarMedicamentos1.IDmedicamento;

        //Agrego el detalle a la lista de detalles que se va guardando en la memoria.
        meds.Add(ordenDetalle);

        //Paso la lista con el nuevo objecto actualizada.
        DetalleMedicamentosOrden = meds;

        //Consulto la lista con para hacer una proyeccion del query y trae el nombre del medicamento
        var medInfo = from a in DetalleMedicamentosOrden                          
                     select new { a,  a.cantidadSol, a.cantidadApr };

        //Cargo la data en el gridview.
        gvMedicamentosOrden.DataSource = medInfo;
        gvMedicamentosOrden.DataBind();

        //Mando a mostrar 
        mpePnMedicamentos.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error basically means that you are trying to add a row to the detail table without providing a legit FK from the master table.

I am guessing this happens when your *if* code block *(txtIDorden.Text.Trim() == "")* is executing which means you are dealing with a brand new *orden* object that does not have any *EntityKey* before saving. I can see that you are trying to explicitly set the detail object to the master through *InvOrdenReference* which does not make sense in your scenario. What I suggest is that set it through navigation property and let EF fix it up for you at runtime. So your *foreach* should be something like this:

```
foreach (var item in DetalleMedicamentosOrden) {
    if (item.InvOrdenReference.Value == null) {
        item.InvOrden = orden;                  
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for you answer and it makes sense but when i put the code the way you said i'm still having an error when i try to add and item to the details. The error "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager." but the object is a new one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Which EF version are you using? Also can you please post the code inside ordenRepository.Add() and efUnitOfWork.Save() methods?

Comment: Hi, i'm using entity framework 4 with a template that i download from codeplex that implements the repository pattern.

Comment: public void Add(InvOrden entity)
  {
   Repository.Add(entity);
  }

Comment: public EFUnitOfWork()
  {
   Context = new InventarioSIAIplusEntities();
  }

  public void Save()
  {
   Context.SaveChanges();
  }

Comment: I make some changes to the code and remove the repository template and im having this error :"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'InvOrdenDet_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.InvOrdenDet'.
The statement has been terminated. "